# why use same export name for different js in requirejs shim part

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

```
 shim:{
    angular: {
        exports: "angular" //first export this with angular 
    },
    uirouter:{
      deps:['angular']
    },
    ngResource: {
        deps: ['angular'],
        exports: 'angular'// now doing same here
    },
    app: {
        deps:['angular','uirouter']
    }
}
```

I can't understand why we use same export name for different module configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exports` value can be anything which is defined in the global space. It does not have to be something that is *created* by the module being loaded.

Having a module ike `ngResource` export `angular` is a matter of convenience. It registers itself with Angular and then returns a reference to Angular so that you can do something like:

```
require(['ngResource'], function (angular) {
```

rather than have to specify `angular` as a separate dependency:

```
require(['angular', 'ngResource'], function (angular) {
```

Comment: thanks, it is only used for bundle the different script with one common name, but when we compile this, it will work?

Comment: I'm assuming by "compile" you mean "run `r.js`". If you meant something else, you'll have to clarify. Unless you're doing something else in the configuration of `r.js` that would cause problems with the build, then there won't be a problem. `r.js` is able to trace the chain of dependencies.